# Rails: include related object in JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a note class that belongs to a user (ie a user can create many notes).

clip from my notes controller

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  # GET /notes
  # GET /notes.xml
  def index
    @notes = Note.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC")
    respond_with @notes
  end
```

When I ask for the index in json results for example /notes.json, it returns the notes but only returns user_id for the user object.  I would like it to also include user.username (and would be curious how to have the whole user object embedded).

Bonus question:  I could not find a way to make the column show as author_id and have it relate back to user.  If this is easy to do, how do you do it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm not sure the new `respond_to`/`respond_with` style is flexible enough to do this. It very well may be, but as far as I understand, it's meant to simplify only the simplest cases.

You can achieve what you are trying to do with the old-style `respond_to` with a block, however, by passing parameters to `to_json`. Try something like this:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notes = Note.order("created_at desc")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render :json => @notes.to_json(:include => { :user => { :only => :username } })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect!  That got me to where I needed to go. Was able to add back in html support easy after getting the json part to work as you showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Jbuilder(https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to response with data very flexible.

```
@notes = Note.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC")
```

and in your index.json.jbuilder file, you can

```
json.extract! @note
json.username @note.user.username
```

Answer (score -1):

Would it be possible to do it the other way around?

```
def index
  @user = User.includes(:notes).order("created_at DESC")
  respond_with @user
end
```

It would be expensive to include user objects each time the `@notes` is iterated.

Comment: I am trying to get all the notes including the username who created it.  This would just return all the users, not solving my problem.