# Master-detail view in Rails with one SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, partial-views, master-detail

Currently I have a JSON view (.json.erb) of following structure:

```
[
<% @master_entities.each do |master| %>
  {
   "attr1": <%= master.attr1 %>,
   "attr2": <%= master.attr2 %>,
   "attr3": <%= master.attr3 %>,
   "attr4": <%= master.attr4 %>,
   "details1": <%= render 'detail_view1', {master: master} %>,
   "details2": <%= render 'detail_view2', {master: master} %>
  },
<% end %>
]
```

detail views have following structure:

```
[
<% Detail_entity1.find_all_by_master_id(master.id).each do |detail1| %>
  {
   "attr1": <%= detail1.attr1 %>,
   "attr2": <%= detail1.attr2 %>,
   "attr3": <%= detail1.attr3 %>
  },
<% end %>
]
```

which results in additional queries for each master entity.

I do not like the fact that I am querying the details model in a view.

I could execute one solid query for master and details, but at first I am afraid that it will consume a lot of memory and at second - how to group entries for master using Ruby on Rails means? And how to extract details by master.id from the whole array?

Or may be there is another way to do the task efficiently?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do. Please include your Rails version and the involved models and their associations.

Comment: Where are you getting your json for master_entity?

Comment: @Edward: in a .json.erb view. I am getting the master entities array in a controller, and forming JSON from it in a view.

Comment: Try doing something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582121/rails-include-related-object-in-json-output to include the details in the master json

Comment: @Edward: What if I have to output not the all object's properties and process object fields in a specific way (I mean - use ternary operators, call additional methods etc.)? Additionally, there are many articles not encouraging the use of to_json, and I decided to follow their advices.

Comment: You could think about building the hash in a method on your master model